# Jquery - Textbox accepts numbers not more than 24 & 60

Tags: javascript, jquery, textbox

I am taking user input as time, so i have 2 textboxes on the page.
1st is for Hour & 2nd is for Minutes.

My validations are :-

- Only 2 numbers allowed in textbox.
- 1st Textbox takes only numbers upto 24
- 2nd Textbox takes only numbers upto 60

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/8tn9h5cu/)

```
$(".TO").on('keyup keypress blur change', function (e) {
    if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {
        return false;
    } else {
        if ($(this).val().length >= parseInt(2) && (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

I am stuck in 2nd & 3rd Validation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `max` attribute , set to `"24"` at first `input` , `"60"` at second `input`

```
$(".TO").on('keyup keypress blur change', function (e) {
    if (+this.value > +this.max) {
      this.value = this.max
    }
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/8tn9h5cu/3/

Comment: I tried to type 3 in first box and 9 in second, but it take the max value. And also by using increment arrows.

Comment: @Bharadwaj See updated post. Cast `this.value` , `this.max` as number